# Why does this LLVM IR code lead to a segfault?

Tags: malloc, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm making a programming language and I'm trying to implementing arrays.
This is the IR code that my compiler generated and I'm having trouble figuring out what might be wrong with it.

I allocate 8 bytes with malloc and I store the pointer as i32.
Then convert it to a i32* and attempt to write 65 (ascii 'A') to it
After that I try to read back the value and write it to stdout.

```
declare i32 @putchar(i32)
define i32 @readByte(){
  %out = call i32 @getchar()
  ret i32 %out
}
    
declare i32 @getchar()
define void @writeByte(i32 %value){
  call i32 @putchar(i32 %value)
  ret void
}
    
declare i32 @malloc(i32)
    

define i32 @main() {
  
  %returnValue = alloca i32
    %id910082450.val = add i32 0, 0
    store i32 %id910082450.val, i32* %returnValue
    
%arr = alloca i32
        %id399214524.val = add i32 0, 8
    %id594130153.val = call i32 @malloc(i32 %id399214524.val)
    
    store i32 %id594130153.val, i32* %arr
    
%id137404173.val = add i32 0, 65
%id174826494.tmp = load i32, i32* %arr
%id174826494.tmp2 = inttoptr i32 %id174826494.tmp to i32*
store i32 %id137404173.val, i32* %id174826494.tmp2
    
    %id723212344.tmp = load i32, i32* %arr
%id723212344.tmp2 = inttoptr i32 %id723212344.tmp to i32*
%id723212344.val = load i32, i32* %id723212344.tmp2
    
    call void @writeByte(i32 %id723212344.val)
    
  %returnValue.tmp = load i32, i32* %returnValue
ret i32 %returnValue.tmp
      
}
```

The error I get is
`2265 Segmentation fault      ./out.bin`

Comment: "I store the pointer as i32" Why? And what's your target platform? Is it 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I stored the pointer as an i64 and it works now, thanks! :)

Comment: Great, but still: why not declare `malloc`'s return type as a pointer in the first place? That is what it returns after all. For 64-bit platforms, you'll also want to declare `malloc`'s parameter as `i64` rather than `i32`.

Comment: I don't have time for a real answer, but I have a realer comment: Whatever you do, use verifyModule() and/or verifyFunction() to catch simple mistakes. The verifier catches **so much** that you'd otherwise spend brain cells on.

Comment: @sepp2k Becouse I need to use the add instruction with the pointer, and it's easier to have it already as an int as opposed to having to convert it from pointer to int

Comment: @kess Unless I'm missing it, it doesn't look like you're using `add` on the result of `malloc` in the code that you've shown. Anyway, the proper way to perform pointer arithmetic (assuming that's what you want to use `add` for) would be using GEP.